# Nginx proxy_cache not caching much

Tags: caching, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I enabled Nginx proxy caching by adding the following to my nginx conf...

```
proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m inactive=60m max_size=10g use_temp_path=off;
```

... and then to the "location /" block within my "server" block...

```
proxy_cache my_cache;
proxy_cache_revalidate on;
proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
proxy_cache_lock on
```

After restarting Nginx, it created the /etc/nginx/cache folder. Also, as traffic went to my site, it created two subfolders, each with a subfolder of their own that contain one single cache file. So it seems to be working. But is that all that would be created/cached? I expected there to be lots of cache files as more and more files were cached? There is considerable traffic to the site so it's definitely not a case of it only getting little traffic and therefore only caching two files. But maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Do you have a `proxy_cache_valid` directive? Did you set a `proxy_cache_key`? Did you have a `add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;` to see what is a hit vs miss?

Comment: Can you add the response headers of a request that should be cached?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @ShawnC.
I don't have "proxy_cache_valid". I set it up following https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/ and my understanding from that guide is "proxy_cache_valid" is only required if I have "proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;" which I don't.
I didn't set a "proxy_cache_key", is that necessary?
Do I just add "add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;" below where I have "proxy_cache_lock on"?

Comment: All the questions are in an attempt to figure out what is wrong. The more information the better. Not that you did anything wrong. Yes add the header after the `proxy_cache_lock`.